# Mysql Stored Procedure - Spatial functions

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, gis, spatial

I wanted to update mysql table column using stored procedure. Data type of the  column is polygon (spatial data)

```
SET boundryData = (SELECT boundry FROM tbl_data WHERE tbl_id = currentRow);
SET updatedBoundry = ST_GeomFromText(boundryData);
```

gives and error saying  that invalid data provided to the function and if I hard corded the same data set as follows the stored procedure works as intened

```
SET updatedBoundry  = ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((6.546269854000059 80.15311213900003,6.54627481600005 80.15298415800004,6.546251038000038 80.15310380500006,6.546269854000059 80.15311213900003))');
```

Whole stored procedure as follows

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE rowCount INT;
    DECLARE boundryData longtext;
    DECLARE currentRow INT;
    DECLARE updatedBoundry polygon;

    SET rowCount=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_kml_data);
    SET currentRow = 1;
    myUpdateLoop: WHILE (currentRow <= rowCount) DO
        SET @boundryData = (SELECT boundry FROM tbl_kml_data WHERE tbl_id = currentRow);
        SET updatedBoundry  =ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((6.546269854000059 80.15311213900003,6.54627481600005 80.15298415800004,6.54605968900006 80.15315188800008,6.546251038000038 80.15310380500006,6.546269854000059 80.15311213900003))');        
        /*SET @updatedBoundry = ST_GeomFromText( @boundryData);*/

        UPDATE tbl_kml_data SET f_polygon = ST_GeomFromText(@boundryData) WHERE tbl_id = currentRow;

        SET currentRow = currentRow + 1;
    End WHILE myUpdateLoop;

END
```

any idea of how to solve this issue

Comment: Provide us with the exact error.

Comment: added the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need a stored procedure to update the table?. A simple update can do the job:

```sql
UPDATE `tbl_kml_data`
SET `f_polygon` = `boundry`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee1ff536cd722f2715e18e45322b4727).

If you really need to use the stored procedure you can do something like:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `new_procedure`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE `rowCount`, `currentRow` BIGINT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE `boundryData` LONGTEXT;
  DECLARE `updatedBoundry` POLYGON;

  SET `rowCount` := (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `tbl_kml_data`
  );
  SET `currentRow` := 1;

  `myUpdateLoop`: WHILE (`currentRow` <= `rowCount`) DO
    SET `boundryData` := (
      SELECT ST_AsText(`boundry`)
      FROM `tbl_kml_data`
      WHERE `tbl_id` = `currentRow`
    );
    -- SET `updatedBoundry` := ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((6.546269854000059 80.15311213900003,6.54627481600005 80.15298415800004,6.54605968900006 80.15315188800008,6.546251038000038 80.15310380500006,6.546269854000059 80.15311213900003))');
    -- SET `updatedBoundry` := ST_GeomFromText(`boundryData`);

    UPDATE `tbl_kml_data`
    SET `f_polygon` = ST_GeomFromText(`boundryData`)
    WHERE `tbl_id` = `currentRow`;

    SET `currentRow` = `currentRow` + 1;
  END WHILE `myUpdateLoop`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ffd1738a18b7abd8f9a7630af6ae658c).

It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) and routine variables [13.1.17 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html), are different variables (`@boundryData` != `boundryData`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. wanted to do the other way round.  wanted to convert long/lat string into Polygon and save as polygon in mysql db. at present data stored in longtext format. error occurs when string parse to ST_GeomFromText function.

Comment: @ChamilaLakmal: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92d5b101dd8d061a16a063122802cf40) and [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=289d4216c61cbf4687124d257e768029).